Pagination numbers in pnp search result template is not visible
We have a search result template and the background of the page is white and so is the pagination text, so it is invisble to the user. Can someone help how to style it as black? But the highlighted and the other pagination numbers. This is the template:
<content id="template">

    <style>

    </style>

    <div class="template_root">
        {{#if @root.hasPrimaryOrSecondaryResults}}   
            {{#if showResultsCount}}
                <div class="template_resultCount">
                    <label class="ms-fontWeight-semibold">{{getCountMessage @root.paging.totalItemsCount keywords}}</label>
                </div>
            {{/if}}
            <pnp-details-list data-items="{{JSONstringify items}}" data-columns-configuration="{{JSONstringify detailsListColumns}}" data-show-file-icon="{{@root.showFileIcon}}" data-is-compact="{{@root.isCompact}}"></pnp-details-list>
            {{#if @root.paging.showPaging}}
                <pnp-pagination 
                    data-total-items="{{@root.paging.totalItemsCount}}" 
                    data-hide-first-last-pages="{{@root.paging.hideFirstLastPages}}"
                    data-hide-disabled="{{@root.paging.hideDisabled}}"
                    data-hide-navigation="{{@root.paging.hideNavigation}}"
                    data-range="{{@root.paging.pagingRange}}" 
                    data-items-count-per-page="{{@root.paging.itemsCountPerPage}}" 
                    data-current-page-number="{{@root.paging.currentPageNumber}}"
                >
                </pnp-pagination>
            {{/if}}
        {{else}}
            {{#unless showBlank}}
                <div class="template_noResults">{{@root.strings.NoResultMessage}}</div>
            {{/unless }}
        {{/if}}
    </div>
</content>

<content id="placeholder">
    <style>
        /* Insert your CSS overrides here */
    </style>

    <div class="placeholder_root">
        {{#if showResultsCount}}
            <div class="template_resultCount">
                <span class="shimmer line" style="width: 20%"></span>
            </div>
        {{/if}}
        <pnp-details-list data-columns-configuration="{{JSONstringify @root.detailsListColumns}}" data-show-file-icon="{{@root.showFileIcon}}" data-is-compact="{{@root.isCompact}}" data-show-shimmers="true"></pnp-details-list>
    </div>

</content>

